# AJAX not receiving PHP content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I am trying to put an infinite scroll on my articles using AJAX and it doesn't get any content from the PHP page. I am using PDO to access the database. I've tried using normal limit 0, 12 and it loads fine.

Here is what I have done so far:

chapter.php :

```
<?php
    include("includes/init.php");
    $query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `test_db` WHERE `test_db`.`Chapter` LIKE :chapter ORDER BY `id` ASC");
    $chapter= (isset($_GET['chapter']) === true) ? $chapter= htmlentities($_GET['chapter']) : die(header('Location:..'));
    $query->bindValue(':chapter', '%'. $chapter . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $number= $query->rowCount();      
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<ul>
<script>
  var page = 1;
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    page++;
    var actual_count = "<?php echo $number; ?>";
    if ((page-1)* 12 < actual_count){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.php",
            data:{ 'page': page },
            success: function(res) {$(".container ul").append(res);}
        });
    }
}
</script>
</ul>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

data.php :

```
<?php 
    include("includes/init.php");
    $page= $_POST['page'];
    $articles = (($page- 1) * 12) . ", 12";
    $articles=$query->prepare("SELECT * FROM `test_db` WHERE `test_db`.`Chapter` LIKE :chapter ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT $articles");
    $chapter= (isset($_GET['chapter']) === true) ? $chapter= htmlentities($_GET['chapter']) : die(header('Location:..'));
    $query->bindValue(':chapter', '%'. $chapter . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);        
    $articles->execute();
    $rows= $articles->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
    foreach ($rows as $row){
        echo "<li>".$row['Name']."-".$row['Description']."</li>";
    };
exit;
?>
```

Comment: You're not calling `bindValue()` in `data.php`.

Comment: `test)db`.`Chapter` typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  var articles_count = "<?php echo $number; ?>";
  while ((page-1)* 12 < articles_count){
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "data.php",
      data:{ 'page': page },
      success: function(res) {
      $(".container ul").append(res);}
    });
  }
```

Comment: and remove var data = { page: page }; ?

Comment: Yes.Because that's what you are doing as data:{ 'page': page }.So remove var data = { page: page };

Comment: That wierd data is what you are echoing form the php script

Comment: Ok, but the data.php should access the database while the index.php is static.. so why echo the index?

Comment: ok, this is why i'm getting the index.thml  - : die(header('Location:..'));

Comment: I think I need to put the $_GET['chapter'] superglobal into the script in order for it to work?..

Comment: it works, i needed to at the chapter variable as POST but now it doesn't work for all monitors.. if i set min-height too low it doesn't work on big ones, if i set it too high it leaves allot of white space on small monitors.. ? where did i go wrong

Comment: yup, added chapter variable as post and all works great, ty @Deepu